# How can I write an assertion to ensure my exception is caught for an AOP spring class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-test

I am trying to write some tests for this class which should catch exceptions and log them. However, when I run the tests they fail. My tests are shown below.  I am not quite sure how the tests should be written, I have just shown my attempt here. What I am trying to achieve is to ensure the aspect I set up catches the exception by doing a JUnit assert. I also know that the right method is matched by the pointcut because IntelliJ IDEA jumps to the method matched by the pointcut when I click the symbol to the left of the IDE. Does my test make sense as I am new to writing tests for AOP? Furthermore, the aspect is not being invoked when the test is run.

```java
interface UserSearch {
    User findUser(long userId); 
    // ...  
}
```

```java
@Service
public class UserSearchImpl implements UserSearch{
     UserRepository userRepository;

     @Autowired
     UserSearchImpl(UserRepository userRepository){
         this.userRepository = userRepository;
     }

    public User findUser(long userId){
       User user = userRepository.findById(userId);
       if(Objects.isNull(user))){
          throw new UserNotFoundException("User with id "+userId);
       }
    } 
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component 
 public class UserSearchAspect {

  @AfterThrowing(
    pointcut = "execution(* com.isf.services.findUser(..))",
    throwing = "userNotFoundException"
  )
  public void logForUser(JoinPoint joinPoint , UserNotFoundException userNotFoundException) 
  {
  }
}
```

```java
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class , MockitoExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest
public class UserSearchAspectTest {

    @MockBean
    UserRepository userRepository;
    UserSearch userSearch;
    UserSearch proxyService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        userSearch = new UserSearchImpl(userRepository);
        AspectJProxyFactory factory = new AspectJProxyFactory();
        factory.setTarget(userSearch);
        factory.addAspectUserSearchAspect.class);
        proxyService = factory.getProxy();
    }

    @Test //this passes
    public void test(){
        assertTrue(AopUtils.isAopProxy(proxyService));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSome(){
        when(userRepository.findById(123L))
            .thenThrow(new UserNotFoundException("User not found "+123));
        /// How do I assert the exception is caught??
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception will be intercepted by the aspect. You would be unit testing the spring AOP code if you are verifying that behaviour. You may verify the logic within the advice.

Comment: Also [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) is already annotated with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Comment: `@Autowired UserSearch userSearch` should inject the dependency and `userSearch.findUser(123L)` should ideally result in the interception

Comment: Yes, that is what I I am trying to do, i.e. test the Advice That's my question. i am stuck on continuing from what I have done. I'm not sure how to proceeed

Comment: What do you plan to do once you intercept ? How is the logging done from `logForUser()`? Are you using any library for logging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following test code can be used to verify

1. The advice getting triggered
2. The exception on user not found

Hope this helps

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;

@SpringBootTest
class UserSearchTest {

    @MockBean
    UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    UserSearch search;

    @SpyBean
    UserSearchAspect aspect;

    @Test
    void test() {
        UserNotFoundException unfEx = new UserNotFoundException("User not found " + 123);
        when(repository.findById(123L)).thenThrow(unfEx);
        Exception exception = assertThrows(UserNotFoundException.class, () -> {
            search.findUser(123L);
        });
        String expectedMessage = "User not found 123";

        // Verify the exception message
        assertTrue(exception.getMessage().contains(expectedMessage));

        ArgumentCaptor<JoinPoint> arg1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(JoinPoint.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<UserNotFoundException> arg2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UserNotFoundException.class);
        // Verify the aspect on exception
        verify(aspect, times(1)).logForUser(arg1.capture(), arg2.capture());
        assertTrue(arg2.getValue().getMessage().contains(expectedMessage));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a ton. Precisely what I wanted. Many thanks RG.